# What is the standard range hood clearance?

Tags: kitchens

What is the proper distance between the top of a kitchen range and the bottom of a basic hood fan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a specific answer. Different manufactures will tell you in their literature which is the appropriate height for their pieces. However a decent range falls between 26" and 34"

Comment: +1. Check the manufacturers documentation. I've seen anywhere between 24" min. to 36" max., although 30"-36" seems to be the most common.